# How to pass the $_SESSION value after using AJAX

Tags: php, ajax, function, session, call

I am trying to get an IF-statement to respond to a change in $_SESSION['view'] value, after using AJAX to filter query results.  However, the IF-statement is not nested within the AJAX div section, rather it is adjacent and below.

What I think I need, is perhaps a function within AJAX page to call for the reload of this IF-statement, thereby checking for the new $_SESSION['view'] value.

This is my present structure.

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<body>
    <div class="content">Content Here
         <div class="filters">
             <select name="view">View
                 <option value="standard">Standard</option>
                 <option value="gallery">Gallery</option>
             </select>
         </div><!--END filters-->
         <div class="show"> Ajax Results Here </div>
    </div>
    // below displays the adjacent DIV
    <?php
    $sess == ($_SESSION['view'])
    if(!isset($sess)||($sess=='standard')){
        echo '<div>standard</div>'
    } else {
        switch ($sess) {
            case 'gallery' : echo '<div>gallery</div>';
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

I have tried to initiate the refresh with the following on the (external) AJAX page;

```
$prior = $_SESSION['view'];
$_SESSION['view'] = $_REQUEST['view'];  //allows the filter to set the new value
$post = $_SESSION['view']
if($prior !== $post){header('Location:'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?refresh=1');}
```

This did not work, because the Header was already sent (naturally), **but I thought this !== approach was a step in the right direction.**

In the second failed attempt, I tried adding a "refresh-page" code to the AJAX script, but this just reset all the filters values - defeating the point.

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

**How can I get the AJAX (which is included via external file) to trigger the IF-statement to re-check the $_SESSION value?**

Comment: what do you mean, "reload the if"? Each http request is independent of each other? User hits the page, php executes, sends output. If that page sends an ajax request BACK to the same script, then the script is recompiled/executed again. But that's not going to affect the page the ajax request came from, not unless you add some code to modify the page based on the ajax results.

Comment: Basically, within AJAX the User could change the "view" $_SESSION value. So how can I get the IF-statement on the original page to recognize that value was changed?

Comment: it can't, since that code executed only when the page was originally built. Since you're using JS, you'd have to use JS to modify the dom of the page, or do a full-blown reload.

Comment: A full reload just reset the query parameters, rending the filters useless. I've understood that you can change content which comes before the JS dom code, but my IF-statement comes after the AJAX. So how do I write it to change the content which comes after the JS code.